# How do I access object values in various elements to display event data?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am using vue.js to build a events management app. The problem is that I am unable to render the value of each event in the list group to the DOM. It just keeps rendering the curly braces expression to the DOM.

Here is the Js Fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/ufy01L3q/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>events Management</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

  <!-- navigation bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand"><i class = ""></i>  events Management </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- main body of our application -->
  <div class="container" id="events">

    <!-- add an event form -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3>Add an Event</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="form-group">
           <input class="form-control" placeholder="Event Name" v-model="event.name">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
           <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Event Description" v-model="event.description"></textarea>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
           <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" v-model="event.date">
         </div>

         <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on="click: addEvent">Submit</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- show the events -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="list-group">
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-repeat="event in events">
           <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i>
             {{ event.name }}
           </h4>

           <h5>
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" v-if="event.date"></i>
             {{ event.date }}
           </h5>

           <p class="list-group-item-text" v-if="event.description">{{ event.description }}</p>

           <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" v-on="click: deleteEvent($index)">Delete</button>
         </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




 // app.js

   <script>
    new Vue({

        // We want to target the div with an id of 'events'
        el: '#events',

        // Here we can register any values or collections that hold data
        // for the application
        data: {
            event: {
                name: '',
                description: '',
                date: ''
            },
            events: []
        },

        // Anything within the ready function will run when the application loads
        ready: function() {
            // When the application loads, we want to call the method that initializes
            // some data
            this.fetchEvents();
        },

        // Methods we want to use in our application are registered here
        methods: {
            // We dedicate a method to retrieving and setting some data
            fetchEvents: function() {
                var events = [{
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'TIFF',
                        description: 'Toronto International Film Festival',
                        date: '2015-09-10'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'The Martian Premiere',
                        description: 'The Martian comes to theatres.',
                        date: '2015-10-02'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'SXSW',
                        description: 'Music, film and interactive festival in Austin, TX.',
                        date: '2016-03-11'
                    }
                ];
                // $set is a convenience method provided by Vue that is similar to pushing
                // data onto an array
                this.$set('events', events);
            },

            // Adds an event to the existing events array
            addEvent: function() {
                if (this.event.name) {
                    this.events.push(this.event);
                    this.event = {
                        name: '',
                        description: '',
                        date: ''
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    });
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
  <!-- JS -->
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First: you don't properly include Vue. Include it inside `<head>`, and in jsfiddle include just a script url, without tags.

Second: your event binding syntax is wrong: you're trying `v-on="click: addEvent"`, but the proper syntax is `v-on:click="addEvent($event)"` - in this example you also pass `$event` to your method, and you an extract a value like this: `$event.target.value`.